# Appropriately-sized ampersands in smallcaps glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package with the smallcaps option. A few of my acronyms contain ampersands, which are of course unaffected by the smallcaps option, making them an eyesore. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}
\newacronym{MA}{m\&a}{mergers and acquisitions}

\begin{document}

Sentence with \gls{MA} here. 
But \textsc{m}\footnotesize\&\normalsize\textsc{a} looks much better.

\end{document}
```

[image: looks like this]

Is there any way to get glossaries to format the ampersand in the appropriate size for smallcaps text? For now I'm using a workaround:

```
\newacronym{MA}{m{\footnotesize\&}a}{mergers and acquisitions}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you can use OpenType fonts, some of them (e.g., Garvis Pro, Poliphilus MT Pro) do have a small cap ampersand.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use a font that supports a small cap ampersand, you could try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}

\newcommand*{\smallamp}{\textsmaller[2]{\char"26}}
\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\textsc{\let\&\smallamp #1}}

\newacronym{MA}{m\&a}{mergers and acquisitions}

\begin{document}

Sentence with \gls{MA} here.\footnote{\gls{MA} vs \textsc{m\&a}}
Normal use: \textsc{m\&a}.

\end{document}
```

In the main text this produces:

[image: Image showing smaller ampersand in the first instance]

This also works okay in the footnote, which looks like:

[image: Image of smaller footnote text]